# How to write this SQL statement?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I have two tables:

1. Event:

   -id; name; startevent; endevent;  PersonID;
2. RegistracijaKorisnik:

   -id; ime;

Now i have written this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
         "SELECT [id], [name], [eventstart], [eventend] " +
         "FROM [Event] " + 
         "WHERE NOT (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))",
       con);
```

With this only display name , eventstart, eventend. Now I would like to display the name from the Person table and name, eventstart, eventend from event . In the Event table, I would like to join the PersonID from the Event table to the ID field in the Person table. Can you help me?

Edit: All code, and don't know why don't show the p.ime

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2012, 09, 17));
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days);
            DataBind();
        }

    }


 protected DataTable dbGetEvents(DateTime start, int days)
    {

      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
      con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Korisnik;Integrated Security=True";
      //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [id], [name], [eventstart], [eventend] FROM [Event] WHERE NOT (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))", con);
     //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select  e.id as EventId, e.name as EventName, e.eventstart, e.eventend, p.Id as PersonId, p.ime as PersonName from Event e inner join RegistracijaKorisnik p on e.PersonID=p.id where not (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))", con);
      //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT e.id, e.name, e.eventstart, e.eventend, p.ime FROM Event e INNER JOIN RegistracijaKorisnik p ON e.PersonID = p.id WHERE NOT ((e.eventend <= @start) OR (e.eventstart >= @end ))", con);
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT e.id, e.name, e.eventstart, e.eventend, p.ime AS 'Person Name' FROM Event e INNER JOIN RegistracijaKorisnik p ON e.PersonID = p.id WHERE NOT ((e.eventend <= @start) OR (e.eventstart >= @end ))", con);
      da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
      da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", start.AddDays(days));

      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      da.Fill(dt);
      return dt; 


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  e.id as EventId
  ,e.name as EventName
  ,e.startevent
  ,e.endevent
  ,p.Id as PersonId
  ,p.name as PersonName 
  ,p.surname as PersonSurname
  ,p.email
from Event e
join Person p on e.PersonId=p.Id
where not (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))
```

Comment: SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select  e.id as EventId, e.name as EventName, e.eventstart, e.eventend, p.Id as PersonId, p.ime as PersonName from Event e inner join RegistracijaKorisnik p on e.PersonID=p.id where not (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))", con);

Comment: I wrote this but give me this error : DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'name'.

Comment: Check the output names .. the ones after as

Comment: I edit the first post, can you tell me where is the mistake. Names in the database is ok.

Comment: Do you have the ime field in your person table ?

Comment: Yes, i made some changes in the names

Comment: Difficult to say what is wrong, as the query is ok, and it also returns a column named name so your reader should be able to get it correct.

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.eventstart, e.eventend,
       p.Name + ' ' + p.Surname AS 'Person Name'
FROM Event e
INNER JOIN Person p ON e. PersonID = p.ID
WHERE NOT ((e.eventend <= @start) OR (e.eventstart >= @end ))
```

Comment: I wrote this but don't show the p.ime , it's the same like befero only event name, start,end. I edit first post.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this is just a simple join, as follows:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.eventstart, e.eventend, p.name
FROM Event e
   INNER JOIN Person p ON p.Id = e.ID
WHERE NOT ((e.eventend <= @start) OR (e.eventstart >= @end)
```

Comment: SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT e.id, e.name, e.eventstart, e.eventend, p.ime FROM Event e INNER JOIN RegistracijaKorisnik p ON e.PersonID = p.id WHERE NOT ((e.eventend <= @start) OR (e.eventstart >= @end ))", con);

Comment: I wrote this but don't show the p.ime , it's the same like befero only event name, start,end

Answer (score 0):

You have same column names in two tables.

Resolution to this problem is

- you can either use fully qualified column names in query like
  tablename.columnname - i.e. event.id, person.id etc or
- You can use alias lik
  select event as e

which should work